# Got an interview that is expected to be 2.5 hours, but I don't know how I can take the time. What should I do?

Tags: interviewing, new-job

I got an e-mail letting me know that I've passed the phone screen and I have been offered an on-site interview with the company but the email informed me that they expect the interview to last 2.5 hours. It's essentially for a sysadmin position which would be a promotion for me. So I'm at least excited to be interviewed and see more about the company and what they're like.

However, I fairly recently started at my current job and it's one of the busiest times of the year for them. I'm not sure how I can possibly take 3+ hours(after accounting for commute etc) off on a work day, especially when I don't have any time accrued that I can use (I'm going to an out of country wedding in October so I can't use what little time off I have in case I don't get the job). This coupled with the fact that my current company is pretty swamped I'm not sure what to do here.

Comment: So you say you don't have any days off that you can use? Did they mention any specific date and time for your interview? How much is "fairly recently", weeks months?

Comment: They asked me what day works best for me.  But for over 3 hours none of them do.

Comment: Any sick leave you can use? (Assuming you don't need to provide proof of sickness)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm not sure how I can possibly take 3+ hours(after accounting for commute etc) off on a work day, especially when I don't have any time accrued that I can use

Usually one should take one day off for "personal reasons", but seems that you don't have any day off left (I suggest you double check, as if you have it would be the way to go).

You mention in comments that *"they asked me what day works best for me"*, but don't see how you can spare that time in any day. The ways our of this I see are:

- **Schedule it for a day you can leave a bit earlier** (perhaps the slow day of your week), and **at a time that you can reach their facilities** (for example, try leaving at 4-5, and ask for the interview to be at, say, 6-7, more or less depending on your commute time).
- The "opposite" of the above mentioned option. **Schedule it early in the morning, on a day you could arrive a bit late** (considering commute, etc.).
- **Schedule the interview for a weekend**. Some companies also work on Saturdays so there is a chance this is possible (Sundays are more unlikely, but you have nothing to loose by asking if they do).

Bottom line, try to *make some time* for it. If you could "sacrifice" some leisure time, or perhaps wake/sleep a bit earlier/later, it will prove beneficial to you.